# How to not sign in as newly created user in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I register a new user it then redirects me to the `index.aspx` after clicking "register user", which is great.  However it the logs me in as the newly created which I don't want.  It should stay as the "Administrator" who is currently logged in.

Here is my code:

```
protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Default UserStore constructor uses the default connection string named: DefaultConnection
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
        var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = UserName.Text };

        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { }, userIdentity);
            Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            StatusMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

I have noticed that it will log me in as the new user by this code:

```
var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { }, userIdentity);
            Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");
```

I understand that part, but I don't know how to change it so it keeps me logged in as "Administrator" but still create the new user?

Thanks

Comment: Dont run the result.succeeded code, which logs you in as the new one..

Comment: Hi Thank,  I have tried that just now but it doesn't create the user then?

Comment: Hi,  Nevermind.   I removed the code now again and rebuild solutions and is working now. Thanks for your help!!!